# Wordpress custom styles in menu page

Tags: css, plugins

I have added a menu page to my plugin. In the [wp codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page) is described that I can use a seperate .php file for the content of the menu.

```
function register_custom_menu_page() {
   add_menu_page('custom menu title', 'custom menu', 'add_users', 'myplugin/myplugin-index.php', '',   plugins_url('myplugin/images/icon.png'), 6);
}
```

myplugin-index.php

```
<?php
   echo "Admin Page Test";
?>
```

Now I want to use custom styles (.css) in the myplugin-index.php.
How can this be achieved?

BR,

mybecks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#toplevel_page_custom_menu_title{
display:none !important;
}
.update-nag{
height:auto !important;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="update-nag">
<?php
   echo "Admin Page Test";
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can enqueue this way

```
function prefix_add_my_stylesheet() {
        wp_register_style( 'prefix-style', plugins_url('style.css', __FILE__) );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'prefix-style' );
    }
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'prefix_add_my_stylesheet' );
```

Reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_enqueue_scripts#Example:_Load_CSS_File_on_All_Admin_Pages

Comment: Won't this load the CSS file on any single page of the WordPress admin?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [wp_enqueue_style](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style).